# Disabled Mage Core in Admin section

Tags: admin, core

I went in the advanced setting and disabled mage core.  I have no more admin area.  I do I restore mage core.

Comment: Go to core_config_data in the database and search where path = advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_Core, then delete the row. Clear var/cache after. In the future don't use disable module output in the admin and instead edit config files when you want to disable modules (but you'll never want to disable Mage_Core anyways).

Comment: Found Remove Engine lever...

Answer (score 2):

Run the following SQL query in your phpMyAdmin or mysql console:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=0 WHERE path='advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_Core';
```

The query above assuming your database table prefix is empty, otherwise append '*core_config_data*' with your database table prefix, which is defined in '*app/etc/local.xml*'.

After that Flush Magento cache by deleting all subfolders of *var/cache/* directory, or run (ask your hosting to run) the following command in your SSH console:

```
find ./var/cache/ -type f -delete
```

Replace *./var/cache/* in the command above with full path to *var/cache* directory of your Magento installation.